# I cant import the Facebook library

Tags: android, facebook

I´m following the next tutorial to use Facebook on my app, them, In the step five I write the line:  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0' but nothing happends and I can import the library in the step 6.

This is my build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mookup.singup2"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

     dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
     }
```

And in my MainAplication, I have this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

  }
```

I saw the dependencies and they say "compile", but I can´t import the facebook library.

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g0Sb.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens". If this line `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` doesn't give you compile errors than you've imported the library correctly.

Comment: When I write that line the aplication shows an error, I need to import the facebook library but it don´t know about the library

Comment: After you added the library to `build.gradle` did you press `Sync` (sliding down in the top-right corner)?

Comment: No, I did not know about this step, my first time with apis on Android Studio, Sorry. Thanks !!

Comment: That's ok. Did it help eventually?

Comment: remove the `repositories{}` closure out of the `android` closure, that is just strange